# Should we close as duplicate from a different site?

Tags: discussion

While https://english.stackexchange.com/a/315921/76689 may not be a steller answer it does point to a rather nice duplicate of the question.  But the dupe is on ELL.  Can we close the question as a dupe?  Have we discussed this before?

Comment: I don't think the facility exists. The procedure is to migrate, then get the other side to close as duplicate. With ELU and ELL, you might even get the same people to do both parts.

Comment: Related (at least, I touch on this possibility in my answer): http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/could-we-migrate-or-cross-post-excellent-questions-and-answers-to-elu-from-ell There may be other relevant questions too.

Comment: My vtc on that ELU question was for lack of prior research. Perhaps I wouldn't have closevoted if it had been asked on ELL in the first place - but I *might* have. I certainly don't think it's "good enough" to justify voting to migrate. Each site should primarily operate in isolation, and if an OP can't be bothered to even choose the most appropriate site, I wouldn't do his donkey work for him unless the question looked like a genuine asset to the receiving site. We're supposed to be building a knowledge base, not wiping careless newbies' noses for them.

Answer (score 4):

Each SE site stands alone, so no you can't close a question as a duplicate of one on another site.

If it would add something to the other site, you can migrate and propose that it be closed as a duplicate there.  Duplicates are valuable for wayfinding; if the new question asks the question in a way that's different enough from the original that people searching for an answer might encounter either of them, a duplicate is useful.  If they're near-virtual duplicates, though, then having a duplicate link doesn't add much (so certainly wouldn't be worth migrating to create that link).

Finally, the general practice on Stack Exchange is that questions should only be migrated if they're *off-topic* on the original site.  Some sites have overlapping scope; if it's on-topic here then the fact that it would also be on-topic somewhere *else* doesn't matter.  Only consider migration if the question is definitely off-topic *here*.  Then, migrate only if it's a good question and would benefit the other site.  "If it's a good question" is important; if it would just be put on hold as unclear or opinion-based or the like on the other site, then don't send it over.

To quote from [Respect the community -- your own, and others'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/):

> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to *that* community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn't be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** - don't blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it - and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

Comment: No, questions can be migrated if a question is marginally on-topic, but if it would almost certainly get better answers on another site. We often migrate questions from here to Linguistics.SE for example.

Comment: @curiousdannii I hadn't realized that local convention was different.  I've updated this to cite the canonical SE blog post on the subject.